# How can I make my keyframe animation start over smoothly?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

My animation made with keyframes does not have a smooth end and jumps to the start very fast. I have no idea how to make this transition smoother.

When the animation ends and jumps back to the start the first item is not completely visible.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

#flip {
  height: 43px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#flip .content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

#flip h3 {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 0.5em;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: right;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  animation: flip 4s infinite;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

#flip .one {
  background: #CD1517;
}

#flip .two {
  background: #068587;
}

#flip .three {
  background: #F2B134;
}

#flip .four {
  background: #6B50BF;
}

#flip .five {
  background: #4FB99F;
}

@-webkit-keyframes flip {
  0% {
      transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  20% {
      transform: translateY(-43px);
  }
  40% {
      transform: translateY(-90px);
  }
  60% {
      transform: translateY(-135px);
  }
  80% {
      transform: translateY(-180px);
  }
  100% {
      transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="flip">
   <div class="content">
 <h3 class="one">developer</h3>
 <h3 class="two">designer</h3>
 <h3 class="three">programmer</h3>
 <h3 class="four">carodej</h3>
 <h3 class="five">alluneed</h3>
   </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Animation on end can be make animation which makes smooth jump from end to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the problem with the half-visible first item after the animation scrolls to the top, you should apply the same height to all items and properly vertically center the h3-tag. To make that easier, I've adjusted your html a little.

To smoothen the animation, you need to change your keyframes. First use a multiple of the height of your elements for the translateY. Then you have to change the percentages. By letting the transition start at 10% of the animation duration, your first item will be visible for a longer time after the animation restarts.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

#flip {
  height: 43px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#flip .content {
  height: 43px; /* new */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center; /* new */
}

#flip h3 {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 0.5em;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 5px;
  animation: flip 6s infinite; /* changed */
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

#flip .one {
  background: #CD1517;
}

#flip .two {
  background: #068587;
}

#flip .three {
  background: #F2B134;
}

#flip .four {
  background: #6B50BF;
}

#flip .five {
  background: #4FB99F;
}


/* changed */
@-webkit-keyframes flip {
  10%, 100% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  25% {
    transform: translateY(-43px);
  }
  40% {
    transform: translateY(-86px);
  }
  55% {
    transform: translateY(-129px);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translateY(-172px);
  }
}
```

```html
<ul id="flip">
  <li class="content">
    <h3 class="one">developer</h3>
  </li>
  <li class="content">
    <h3 class="two">designer</h3>
  </li>
  <li class="content">
    <h3 class="three">programmer</h3>
  </li>
  <li class="content">
    <h3 class="four">carodej</h3>
  </li>
  <li class="content">
    <h3 class="five">alluneed</h3>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Edit: Animation without scroll to top effect**

In order to have a seamless rotation effect, you need to adjust the translateY values a bit further and add some more keyframes.

*note: The provided code is not perfectly smooth - try to adjust the percentages and translateY values until the animation suites your needs.*

```css
@-webkit-keyframes flip {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(15px);
  }
  10% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  30% {
    transform: translateY(-43px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(-86px);
  }
  70% {
    transform: translateY(-129px);
  }
  90% {
    transform: translateY(-172px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-202px);
  }
}
```

Comment: and what if i need the animation on the end dont doing animation like scroll but animation like noone will see is the end of the div and makes something on the end what makes animation looks like a infinite animation without visible end of animation? thanks for answer

Comment: @MatúšRebroš check out my edit. It should give you a good starting point. It is quite a fiddly task to get the perfect animation, since it depends on the available white space, font size, padding / margin etc.